# LinkedIn website share always showing 1 min read

Tags: html, linkedin-api, meta, share-open-graph

I am trying to figure out how to remove the `1 min read` in the description of when I share content to LinkedIn.

[1 min read example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwvVn.png)

I have the open graph tags on the page, and verified they do not display 1 min read anywhere on the page.  I've also played around with the og:type.  Trying 'article', 'media', 'video', 'website', 'none'

Here is my tags.  Verifying that the variable values do not have any illegal characters being used.

```
        <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $aSocialTitle; ?>">
        
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo $aSocialTitle; ?>">
        <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
        <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $aSocialDescription; ?>">
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $aSocialIcon; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a sitewide issue for LinkedIn.

After speaking to the LinkedIn support and elevating the problem to the tech team I got an answer that:

> This was added for any URL that is shared - this would need to be
> filed as feedback vs. a bug.

In other words according to LinkedIn, this is not a bug, it's a feature.

I don't think they will be fixing it any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

I was also experiencing this issue and LinkedIn Support gave me similar answers to [regress_that's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66024237/542517).

> "There's no way to change this metric because it's calculated with machine learning and shared by the LinkedIn algoritm (sic)."

Considering it works for some sites and not others, I was determined to figure out root cause for myself.

One potential cause is if your site is a Single-Page Application (SPA). LinkedIn's tooling to calculate this metric will fail because there is no content in your HTML for it to evaluate. LinkedIn's tooling does not operate with JavaScript enabled, or at least, it does not evaluate the DOM generated by SPA frameworks.

If your site is a SPA and this metric is important to you, consider pre-rendering your site. Honestly, if you are concerned with sharing on social media sites, you're likely concerned about SEO as well, so pre-rendering is going to do you all kinds of service.

How to pre-render depends on the SPA framework you are using, so do some searches to find out how to get started on that front.